how to remove url from string?
How can I remove the url from a string? I url might not start with https or http. How can I do this using javascript? I want to prevent people from sending bad urls to my users through the sign up form.

Can you provide examples?

If it doesn't have to start with a scheme like http: how do you define a URL? foo/bar.html can be a URL or a filename.

something like foo.com or foo.net or https://example.com or http://example.com @Barmar

Those are domain names, not URLs.

What do you mean by sending bad urls through the signup form? What part of a signup form is sent to other users?

Training.   Train your users not to click on links from your sign-up form.  If your users are "seeing" the forms on a website/app then encode the sign-up form's values so they aren't converted to links.

So what happens is that an attacker can sign up as a user and get an email from us. IF they put an evil url as the first name, the url shows up in the email the user gets from us and the user clicks on that url. Mail clients make all sorts of urls like example.com, http://example.com, https://www.example.com clickable. Trying to prevent that.

URLs can have schemes other than http: or https:, also ftp:, mailto:, and others (proposed, obsolete, and other - https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml). Apart from the scheme: part and //, not much separates a url from just even normal sentences, like a recipe that calls for butter/margarine/cooking oil, or listing search engines like google.com/bing.com/etc.

Sounds like you want to forbid also all kinds of [\w]+\.[\w]+ (and probably some other characters than \w). Seems to be a long shot.

The most secure way would probably be to validate the name and not allow certain characters like periods there at all, which is not a character required for names.

Restrict characters allowed in names to avoid those needed for urls, or escape them so they're not parsed as urls.

If an attacker puts an evil url as their name and receive an email with their evil url in it, that seems like it's on them?

You can use a regular expression that matches the URLs and replace them with an empty string using the .replace() method.
  function removeURLs(text) {
    // Regular expression to match URLs
    const urlRegex = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    // Replace URLs with an empty string
    return text.replace(urlRegex, '');
  }


Hi it doesn't remove example.com but it does remove  http://example.com. Sometimes the example.com doesn't have http or https preprended.

You should definitely use regular expressions.
You can find the answer of how to create a regular expression for URLs here: What is a good regular expression to match a URL?
Once you have this regular expression, you can do something like this: (And make sure the regular expression has the g modifier flag to cath all instances)
var myStr = ...;
const regex = ...;
myStr.replace(regex, "");

